# node js post 404 not found with router

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, router

hello i have a issue i build a project when i start to add the server side
i am using node js express
i create fetch post to spesific url from the database (mongoDB)
and i want to add the users
now
its workd but i try to reconfigure the files and using router and now i get 404 when i try to make the post is upload some code

just need to know where is the bad request
the url i want to fetch is
http://localhost:5000/shopping-cart/user/sign-up

```
    Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/shopping-cart/user/sign-up", user).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });


const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const path = require("path")
const productRouter = require("./routes/product.route");
const userRouter = require("./routes/user.route");
const { setServerConfiguration } = require("./config");

setServerConfiguration(app);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/shopping-cart-data-base');

app.use("/shopping-cart", productRouter);

app.use("/user/sign-up", userRouter);


app.listen(5000);

const router = require('express').Router();
const errorsHandler = require('../utils/errorsHandler');
const UserModel = require('../models/User');

router.post("/user/sign-up", async (req, res) => {
    let body = req.body;
    console.log(body)
    try{
        await UserModel.create({
            name: body.name,
            username: body.username,
            password: body.password,
            shoppingHistory: [],
          });
          res.send(body);
    }catch(e){
        return errorsHandler(e, req, res);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `user.route` - what is it? Rename to `user`

Answer (score 1):

Your router is mounted on the `/user/sign-up` prefix:

```
app.use("/user/sign-up", userRouter);
```

Which means that all requests that start with `/user/sign-up` will get passed to your router.

Your router should be routing *relative* to that prefix, so to make it work, use this:

```
router.post('/', ...)
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the response so i need to make : router.post('/',...) and on the app make app.use("/user/sign-up,userRouter)

Answer (score 0):

404 route not found

```
app.use("/shopping-cart", productRouter) => route1

app.use("/user/sign-up", userRouter); => route2
```

route1 other route2

url http://localhost:5000/shopping-cart request route1

url  http://localhost:5000/user/sign-up request route2

Answer (score 0):

Try this url

```
"http://localhost:5000/user/sign-up"
```

If you want to use "http://localhost:5000/shopping-cart/user/sign-up" than you need to define route like that, for example:

```
router.post("shopping-cart/user/sign-up", async (req, res) => {

//Your code
})
```

Comment: it didnt work it still get the 404 and i dont know why 
something is wrong i try multiple version of solution and try to change once the router once the app.use and it still wont work

Comment: Did you tried with this URL "http://localhost:5000/user/sign-up" ?

Comment: Your productRouter is not containing "/user/sign-up" this route that's why giving 404 status

Comment: Yeah ok it working now i was confused because when i choose the correct url i get error 400 (bad request) so it mean that it found the url but i was having a problem with my schema in data base so i fix it thank you so much! Need to note myself that error 400 it mean that it found the url but get any error on the fetch